# SQL Server Reporting Services. Calculate the total value in a cell when the row is grouped in gender

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, business-intelligence, ssrs-expression

### I have a table in my SSRS report with grouped rows for gender and one row has total values. So my table in short looks like this:

```
NumOfGenders   %Gender    Total Salaries    GenderSalaries in %  
Female    countRows ()      ?       [Sum][Salaries]           ?  
Male      CountRows ()      ?       [Sum][Salaries]           ?  
Total     CountRows ()      ?       [Sum][Salaries]           ?
```

---

I don´t figure out to get the expressions to count for the number of both genders in % and Total salaries in % for both genders. 
I want % gender to be for example female (countRows for female)/(count rows for the whole set)*100. So I get the share of female and male in the table. For The total Salaries I want the female share of the total Salaries to be salaries for (female)/(Total salaries)*100. The expression in the rows for salaries is:

```
=Sum(Fields!Salaries.value)
```

So I want something like this:

```
 =(Sum(Fields!Salaries.value "females")/(Sum(Fields!Salaries.value "Total")*100
```

So how do I get the genders specifik values in the expressions?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your table is having a group as "Gender" and you are having a sub-total field to calculate total. Say you are pulling these data from a Dataset named as ds_dataset.

In this case you can put below expression in your gender % field.

```html
=(Sum(Fields!gender.value)*100)/Sum(Fields!gender.value,"ds_dataset")
```

Here the "ds_dataset" is your dataset name.

For salary % similarly you can put below code.

```html
=(Sum(Fields!Salaries.value)*100)/Sum(Fields!Salaries.value,"ds_dataset")
```

Let me know if this is not clear.

Comment: I solved my problem by populate an variabel with the entire dataset, so it´s the same thing as you show here really. Thanks.